# Toolbar Bug when show keyboard

Tags: java, android

I'm setting the background color of the toolbar programmatically on the main activity's onCreate.

```
    toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    settings = getSharedPreferences(Constants.SETTING, 0);

    primaryColor = settings.getString("primaryColor", "#5500FF");
    appName = settings.getString("appName", "Catálogo");
    colorPrimaryDraw = new ColorDrawable(Color.parseColor(primaryColor));

    //setar nome do app e cor de fundo no toolbar
    toolbar.setTitle(appName);
    toolbar.setBackground(colorPrimaryDraw);
    toolbar.setTitleTextColor(Color.WHITE);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
```

[toolbar ok](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ryBEW.png)

But when the keyboard is open the part of the toolbar icon changes to another color.

[Open keyboard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h52jc.png)

Any tips on how to solve this?

XML:

```
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@null"
    android:backgroundTint="@null"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="@null"
        android:backgroundTint="@null"
        app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
```

XML menu

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/toolbar_alertas">
<item
    android:id="@+id/action_alertas"
    android:orderInCategory="100"
    android:title="Alertas"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_alert"
    app:showAsAction="always" />
```

Comment: Your toolbar xml?

Comment: Sorry for that, I already edited.